# SQL create empty database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

when I create database in sql server, it creates some tables by default inside new database from another one, which I had created earlier, can anyone pls tell me why this is happening and how to prevent it?

I am using the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Databasename]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're creating a new database, not copying? Please post some examples of your problem.

Comment: How did you create said database?

Comment: I'm sure that I create new database..

Comment: Create Database [database name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have not modified model database

The model database is used as the template for all databases created on an instance of SQL Server

Comment: Thats the idea, maybe I have accidently done it. Thanks a lot I'll check it

Comment: Give us a feedback :)

Comment: It was exactly as you said bro. Thanks again